# What does a straight line connecting notes on different clefs mean?

Tags: piano, notation

What is the meaning of the straight lines between notes in opposite staves, as shown in the picture? I keep seeing it, but Google and Wikipedia are not helping me.

[image]

Comment: I just have to ask, where did this music come from?  I keep seeing questions like this with such terrible formatting.

Comment: At a guess, this is from the _Ricercar a 6_ from the Musical Offering, @MattPutnam. That is why the "surplus" of rests. To be fair, this would be a very difficult piece to format on a Grand Staff.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It means quite simply that the voice in question is moving between the staves (and usually between the hands as well). In this case, the voice starting with G above middle C falls an octave to be continued in the left hand until it returns to G below middle C, then rises back up an octave to be played in the right hand.

Edit: Here is the original score of this passage (m.10ff of the *Ricercar a 6* from the *Musical Offering*). Looking at the range of the individual voices, you can well imagine the number of times voices will cross between staves when this is transcribed to a Grand Staff.

[image: m. 10–12, "Ricercar a 6", Musical Offering]

Answer (score 3):

In Barbershop style notation, such a line indicates that the melody is moving from one voice part to another.  By convention, a voice part does not move from one staff to the other.

In this case, it looks as if one musical line (perhaps on a single-note instrument or voice) moves from the treble clef staff to the base clef staff and then back.  As a singer, I would find this confusing.

Answer (score -3):

If it is for piano then it could be considered to be a Glissandi or Glissando. What guitar players know as a slide.

An example of how this is notated.

[image: Gliss]

[image: gliss2]

Comment: Glissando can be applied to other instruments, right? Besides that, gliss is what came to my mind as well. +1

Comment: It _could_ be a glissando (which is normally specified with _gliss._ over the line), but in this case it isn't; it's voice crossings. I've added the original score to my answer so you can see how the voices were originally notated.

Comment: Isn't glissando meant to be a wavy line, not a straight line connecting cleft. I believe it's moving voices.